# I cannot install WINE

Tags: wine, dependencies

Whenever I try `sudo apt-get install wine-stable`
I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 5.0.1~focal)
Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 5.0.1~focal) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am new to linux and cannot at all figure this out. I tired
`sudo apt-get install wine-stable-amd64`
and
`sudo apt-get install wine-stable-i386`
but both lead to more errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I asume you followed the instructions on https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu. But since elementary OS is based on Ubuntu 18.04, you should have used the ppa for Ubuntu bionic, not focal.

To try and fix the issue:

1. please remove the focal ppa:
   `sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'`
   `sudo apt update`
2. follow the istructions from https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu-18-04/#installing-wine-50-on-ubuntu to install wine.

EDIT:

Since the instructions in the link at step 2 might be unavailable in the future, I'll paste them below (**only of distributions based on Ubuntu 18.04**):

Enable the 32-bit architecture and update the packages list:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386  
sudo apt update
```

Import the WineHQ repository’s GPG key using the following wget command:

```
wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the WineHQ repository to your system:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common  
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

Install FAudio from the OBS repository:

```
wget -qO- https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -  
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/obs.list'  
sudo apt update
```

Install Wine 5.0 package by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Verify the Wine installation:

```
wine --version
```

The output should look something like this:

```
wine-5.0
```

Comment: Thank You! It worked!