# Wine packages are held back

Tags: wine, dependencies

I have some Wine packages held back when updating

````
Listing... Done
wine-stable/bionic 5.0.3~bionic amd64 [upgradable from: 4.0.3~bionic]
wine-stable-amd64/bionic 5.0.3~bionic amd64 [upgradable from: 4.0.3~bionic]
wine-stable-i386/bionic 5.0.3~bionic i386 [upgradable from: 4.0.3~bionic]
michael@BamBam2:/$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  wine-stable
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
michael@BamBam2:/$ sudo apt-get install wine-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 5.0.3~bionic)
               Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 5.0.3~bionic) but 4.0.3~bionic is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
michael@BamBam2:/$ sudo apt-get install wine-stable-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 wine-stable-amd64 : Depends: libfaudio0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
michael@BamBam2:/$ sudo apt-get install wine-stable-i386
[sudo] password for michael:          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libfaudio0:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
michael@BamBam2:/$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.3~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. ```

So it looks like I have a problem with libfaudio0?

Also, why doesn't my second ``` end the code format?
````

Comment: Can you look at the answer here https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/25260/i-cannot-install-wine/25262#25262 for some hints?

Comment: Yes, I had a look at that but I don't think it's the same. It says about removal a focal ppa but I've not got that

Comment: If I'm supposed to adapt solution that to what I have then I don't know how

Comment: Folow the steps detailed there, especially the one about the FAudio package (libfaudio0) is not normally available for distributions based on Ubuntu 18.04. Newer versions of wine depend on it.

Comment: I don't know how to do step 1 though. That problem mentions focal in the error report and the solution says to remove something that has focal in it. My error message mentions bionic, not focal. Where it says about removing a repository do I just swap the word focal for bionic?

Comment: Try the step at 'Install FAudio from the OBS repository...'

Comment: Brilliant, that worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I cannot install WINE](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/25260/i-cannot-install-wine)

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy New Year!