# running DOS/Windows executable in elementary OS?

Tags: wine

Any advice/recommendations, please

as to the best way of running DOS/Windows executable files in elementary OS?

I could switch to Windows just for this simulation program:

(http://www.jf2.com/bcwrr/Dockstader-Valve-Gear.html),

but it would be PITA doing it just for that

(since I already migrated almost everything else to Linux...)

**Compiled from comments / discussion:**

Have tried it today (Aug 11 2021 at 8:48) and:

it seems that input window hiding behind main one is probably just coincidence?, but... there was another/additional window hiding quietly behind main one when things froze

[image: error message]

Deleting this window allowed me to close the program and start again.

**EDIT:**
had another go at editing dimensions, making sure that the input windows was away from main one.

All was going well, until :-)

[image: error messages]

The only way out of this one was to shutdown elementary and start again...

After repeated attempts it all seems to be coming back to **user32.dll**

**one more EDIT:**
if I execute any of these simulation programs from terminal, I get the following error message (although it deosn't stop things running?):

"wine SlipEccen.exe

006c:err:vulkan:wine_vk_init Failed to load libvulkan.so.1."

And finally (Aug 11 2021 at 9:43)...

**It seems the answer is as simple as disabling error message in the simulation program
(go: SetUp > SetErrorBeep Off).**

This allows me to enter new dimensions without things going weird.

I have positively confirmed it by switching it on (things go wrong) and switching it off (works OK).

I don't need to be warned about dimension's error (I know it will be wrong until I complete entering the data) so disabling error message is not a big deal.

Whether it could be made to work by doing something about user32.dll is another story...

but I am happy with the compromise solution.

@Vlad - big thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**WINE**](https://www.winehq.org/) is always the thing i go to when I really need to run some Windows apps on elementary. In your specific case, Dockstader executables seem to run just fine with WINE.

### [image: Heading]

I have a detailed answer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/25260/i-cannot-install-wine/25262#25262)  about how to install WINE on elementary OS Hera 5.1> See if that gets you what you need, and let us know if you get into any issues.

EDIT: [**DosBox**](https://www.dosbox.com/) works well for non-win32 applications, you can try it. Easy to install with a simple `sudo apt install dropbox`. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to make the DosBox window go Full screen.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have tried DosBox, but got the message  "This program must be run under Win32" so have given up on it ... so it must be Wine (thank you for info about installing).

Comment: Followed your instructions and ... got wine-6.0.1 instead of 5.0 ?? When I tried to run got the message: "Wine could not find wine-mono package which is needed for .NET applications to work correctly. Wine can automatically download and install it for you. Note:it is recommended to use your distribution's package instead."   -   any advice? please?   PS otherwise it seems to be working OK...

Comment: Next I got the same warning about Gecko package...?

Comment: And a final comment - after all this effort, I am afraid that this particular program doesn't work with Wine   Attempts to input data for new model result in the program freezing in some kind of loop, beeping error sounds and preventing me from doing anything (can't even force shut it down). It plays nicely if you have an existing data file, but modifying it messes it up :-(   It is probably something to do with an ancient Windows executables rather than anything to do with Wine or Linux?

Comment: WINE will do its best to install the needed packages, and you can just approve the messages you see when running the applications for the first time. You may try running 'winecfg' in Terminal and change the WINE Windows versions from 'Windows 10' to Windows XP'.

Comment: You can also install the winetricks package. This will add the ability for you to add missing dll files (sudo apt install winetricks). Start it from the Launcher -> OK to select default WINE prefix -> check Install a Windows DLL or component -> check the packages the program might need (fonts, dotnet)

Comment: To debug the program and see hints for the freezes, you can run your exe files with 'wine AllanLBSC.exe' for example and look in Terminal for the output while using the program. I am not familiar with those programs though, so I might need some help: how do you input data for a new model?

Comment: Thanks Vlad, you modify "frame" and "cylinder" dimension using "EditDim" option. Until you enter all numbers you may have some odd results, (normally just giving error bips, but not crashing/freezing the program, like it does in Wine).     What you seeing initially when you run one of the programs is default model, that needs to be modified to reflect your design.    How do you look in Terminal for the output, please?

Comment: I think I found what the issue is :D. Try this please: open Heywood.exe for example, go to EditDimen -> FrameDimensions -> MOVE FrameDimensions window away from the main drawing window, so they do not overlap -> delete the value from Stroke Length -> press Enter -> beeping starts, and main window comes into focus (emulating a freeze) -> Enter new value for Stroke Length -> beeping stops if valid value, or continues if invalid)

Comment: Our issue is not with the program freezing in beeping mode, but with the Edit window moveing behind the main window when the beeps start. In this case you're no longer able to enter new values in the empty fields (and therefore stop the beeps) and you are also prevented from clicking the ResetFrameDim button.

Comment: Another way around this seems to be resizing the 'frozen' beeping window until the edit one become available. The resizing animations might look a bit funky though... basically make sure the main window and the edit window do not overlap, because the main window will steal focus to display the error warning and to beep your ears off.

Comment: OK, thanks, will try and report back

Answer (score 1):

Tried and installed Bottles app (flatpak) and this seem to work straight away, with no problems at all!

Another very useful solution - get it from AppCenter.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried it today and:

it seems that input window hiding behind main one is probably just coincidence?, but... there was another/additional window hiding quietly behind main one when things froze

[image: error message]

Deleting this window allowed me to close the program and start again.

PS posting it as an answer (even though it is question not an answer) because:

a)Please avoid extended discussions in comments.
Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

b)wanted to include the picture and (I believe) it is not possible in chat

PS I must admit that I am not impressed with stackexchange's funcionality :-(

but hey, it is what it is...

**EDIT:**
had another go at editing dimensions, making sure that the input windows was away from main one.

All was going well, until :-)

[image: error messages]

The only way out of this one was to shutdown elementary and start again...

After repeated attempts it all seems to be coming back to **user32.dll**

**one more EDIT:**
if I execute any of these simulation programs from terminal, I get the following error message (although it deosn't stop things running?):

"wine SlipEccen.exe

006c:err:vulkan:wine_vk_init Failed to load libvulkan.so.1."

Comment: I am amazed at how detailed you managed to dissect the problem :D, and  am sorry it has taken me a long time to return to this discussion. About stackexchange functionality, whenever you need to add new info / screenshots, the proper way s to edit your original question and add it there. Glad you found a compromise, and always keep in mind Wine is not perfect, especially when it comes to legacy windows programs. I will add your new finds to your original question, s that is more readily available to anyone who might stumble upon this issue in the future.

Comment: Thank you! for comment and explanation of stackexchange functionality

Answer (score 0):

And finally...

It seems the answer is as simple as disabling error message in the simulation program

(go: SetUp > SetErrorBeep Off).

This allows me to enter new dimensions without things going weird.

I have positively confirmed it by switching it on (things go wrong) and switching it off (works OK).

I don't need to be warned about dimension's error (I know it will be wrong until I complete entering the data) so disabling error message is not a big deal.

Whether it could be made to work by doing something about user32.dll is another story...

but I am happy with the compromise solution.

@Vlad - big thank you for your help!!